# Access ASP.NET Session in the Background

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm setting a `Session` in my Asp.NET Code like this:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Session["AdminID"] = id;

        return View();
    }
}
```

But now I want to access this `Session` in a file which is not a `Controller` in the background of the project.
**Is this possible?**

S.th. like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Foo()
    {
        return Session["AdminID"]
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by background? a background thread/worker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `HttpContext.Current.Session`:

```
using System.Web;

// ...

public int Foo()
{
  return (int)HttpContext.Current.Session["AdminID"];
}
```

Comment: This approach couples the code to HttpContext and a Session provider so it's untestable and it won't work outside a http request. A much better approach is to inject/set directly the values into the object. This way the code won't care from where the value was from and the coupling is reduced.

Comment: @MikeSW I was answering a concrete question. Of course the better approach would be the one you suggested but we don't know how this code is going to be used and if it's even worth doing it like you proposed.

Comment: I have created a wrapper for HttpContext.Current.Session that I inject into my controllers and helper classes. It makes unit testing easier as I can pass in an inmemory implementation when testing. http://codingsmith.co.za/a-better-way-of-working-with-httpcontext-session-in-mvc/